# Unknown discriminator value "SqlException", How to ignore discriminator on dynamic type

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a model like below:

```cs
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MongoDbLogModel
{
    public string Level { get; set; }

    public string RenderedMessage { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime UtcTimeStamp { get; set; }

    public dynamic Properties { get; set; }

    public dynamic Exception { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the JSON model:

```json
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "61a8dadd1ab0e48d55b06626" },
  "Level": "Error",
  "UtcTimeStamp": { "$date": "2021-12-02T14:40:30.436Z" },
  "MessageTemplate": {...},
  "RenderedMessage": "",
  "Properties": {...},
  "Exception": {
    "_t": "SqlException",
    "HelpLink": null,
    "Source": "Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider",
    "HResult": -2146232060,
    "Message": "Invalid object name 'SystemControlLogs'.",
    "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClien",
    "Data": {...}
  }
}
```

And here is [my code](https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-ui/blob/209778e40758fa3b1cb1dd5e55534b3fc2e8ea0d/src/Serilog.Ui.MongoDbProvider/MongoDbDataProvider.cs#L50) to fetch log data:

```cs
var logs = await _collection
                .Find(builder)
                .Skip(count * page)
                .Limit(count)
                .SortByDescending(entry => entry.Timestamp)
                .ToListAsync();
```

I face `Unknown discriminator value "SqlException"` exception on deserializing data. Is there any way without creating a model for the `Exception` property, to get rid of that exception? (I tried `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MongoDbLogModel>();` but had no luck).

Comment: do you have one too many `}` at the end of your JSON?

Comment: Hi Mohsen :) You reached 10k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably have a type that is checked at runtime. I think dynamic is not supported in MongoDB driver(although It has not been officially stated) and recommended solution is to use BsonDocument instead.

[Mixing Static and Dynamic Data - official documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/examples/mixing_static_and_dynamic/)

I'm not sure BsonDocument is applicable for you but this solution is the simplest one:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MongoDbLogModel
{
    public string Level { get; set; }

    public string RenderedMessage { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime UtcTimeStamp { get; set; }
    
    //changed line
    [BsonElement("Properties")]
    public BsonDocument Properties { get; set; }
    
    //changed line
    [BsonElement("Exception")]
    public BsonDocument Exception { get; set; }
}
```

[Working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tRBzR8)

if BsonDocument doesn't Serve your purpose. you have to implement a custom serializer. something like this:
[Serialize dynamic data with mongodb](https://gist.github.com/mahizsas/de6d44a91af7848d8017)